# php+sql проблема с условием

Tags: php, sql, if

Всем доброго времени суток! уже третий день ломаю голову и не могу понять в чем причина.
есть таблица invite_product ,в ней есть структура id_user и id_product ,есть PHP код:

```
$get_change = "SELECT * FROM invite_product WHERE id_user='.$route[2].' AND id_product='.$route[1].'";
            $change_result = select($get_change);
            
            if (count($change_result) === 0) {
                $insert_invite = "INSERT INTO invite_product (id_user, id_product) VALUES ($route[2], $route[1])";
                execQuery($insert_invite);
            }
```

исходя из кода думаю понято что методов GET и POST тут нету.
Проблема состоит в том что if (count($change_result) === 0) не работает и все равно происходит добавление дублей в базу,а мне нужно что бы соблюдалось условие, если пользователь с ID которое передается в $route[2] уже добавлял некий обьект с ID который присутствует в $route[1] - то добавление этого обьекта происходить не должно.
пробовал создавать функцию которая возвращает true или false при наличие строки в базе ,засовывал функцию в if ,но при множестве моих манипуляций этот код либо добавляет не собюдая условия либо не добавляет в базу совсем ничего.
да чуть не забыл, база MySql ,(id_user и id_product) - тип int, пробовал text ,но все тоже самое.

Если мало информации я добавлю.

```
function select($query) {
global $conn;
$queryResult = [];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $queryResult[] = $row;
    }
}
return $queryResult;
```

}

Comment: Колонки содержат строковое значение, или цифровое?

Comment: содержат ID то есть числовое значение

Comment: Попробуйте для теста использовать не $route[2] и $route[1] а константы, например 1 и 2, код нормально отрабатывает?

Comment: пробовал,$change_result возвращает количество строк то есть count($change_result) через var_dump показывает прибавление ,но if не хочет работать,не могу понять почему

Comment: `count(select($get_change))` точно возвращает числовое значение?

Comment: не числовое,а количество строк,добавил код функции select (возвращает int(2) если конкретика нужна)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в формировании sql запроса, попробуйте заменить

```
$get_change = "SELECT * FROM invite_product WHERE id_user='.$route[2].' AND id_product='.$route[1].'";
```

На

```
$get_change = sprintf('SELECT * FROM invite_product WHERE id_user = %u AND id_product = %u', $route[2],$route[1]);
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек,заработало!